# docker rabbitmq crashing during startup

Tags: python, rabbitmq, docker

Starting (docker run) the rabbitmq image results in a crash. The contents of startup_err:

```
  Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
  init terminating in do_boot ()
```

startup_log

```
  BOOT FAILED
   ===========

   Error description:
     {error,{cannot_create_mnesia_dir,"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost/",
                                eacces}}

   Log files (may contain more information):
        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

   Stack trace:
       [{rabbit_mnesia,ensure_mnesia_dir,0,
               [{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,472}]},
       {rabbit_node_monitor,prepare_cluster_status_files,0,
                     [{file,"src/rabbit_node_monitor.erl"},{line,99}]},
        {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,326}]},
        {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,354}]},
        {init,start_it,1,[]},
        {init,start_em,1,[]}]

         {"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{error,            {cannot_create_mnesia_dir,"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost/",eacces}}}}
```

Here's the rabbitmq portion of the Dockerfile:

```
  RUN apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y

  ENV RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
  ADD rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

  # plugins --offline
  RUN /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
  RUN /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel
  RUN /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management

  EXPOSE 5672 15672 4369
  VOLUME ["/var/log/rabbitmq", "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia"]
```

and here's the docker run command. The rabbitmqbase variable holds the value to the host (my OSX) directory where the volumes are to be mapped to.

```
  fab.local('docker run -itd -h rabbithost -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 4369:4369 -p 9001:9001 -v {}/data/mnesia:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia -v {}/data/log:/var/log/rabbitmq --name rabbitmq dtwill/rabbitmq'.format(rabbitmqbase, rabbitmqbase))
```

So yes, it looks like a rights issue...I'm not sure how to solve it.

[Update]
So I thought it could be the -h param and tried the boot2docker ip, localhost & removed it all together - still crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, rabbitmq can't write to `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` inside the container (which maps to rabbitmqbase + `/data/mnesia` on your host).

The reason for this is likely that `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` does not exist before docker mounts your volume. The mountpoint is therefore created by docker, but owned by user different from rabbitmq.

Make sure that `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` exists in the image before starting the container.